# Criar consulta Linq - EF Lista com n sublistas

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possuo uma lista com N resultados, precisaria fazer alguma mudança no linq para que esta lista retornasse N listas de apenas 3 resultados subjacentes. 
Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
    var resultados = lista.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
                .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Com isto você quebra a sua lista em N listas de 3 resultados.